# Can a component remove its own template and put it back conditionally?

Tags: angular

I am looking at the `*ngIf`'s source code :

```
@Input()
  set ngIf(condition: any) {
    if (condition && !this._hasView) {
      this._hasView = true;
      this._viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this._template);
    } else if (!condition && this._hasView) {
      this._hasView = false;
      this._viewContainer.clear();
    }
  }
```

Can I have a component that does like below?

```
@Component({})
class MyComponent{

     constructor ( 
              public _template : TemplateRef,
              public _viewContainer : ViewContainerRef) {
    }

   onSomeButtonClick(condition){
       if(condition){
          removeMyView();
       }else{
          putTheViewBackIfItsRemoved();
        }
   }
}
```

Trying to use `ngIf`'s logic inside the component doesn't work, which I think it's because the viewContainerRef for the component is empty

EDIT :

Just to mention that I'm not looking to hide the view , I just want to remove it from the DOM.

In other words, can we something like `ngIf` of host elements ?
I know you can't put a directive on `host`, that's why I thought maybe with `ViewContainer` and `TemplateRef` you could achieve the same.

The other thing is, having worked with Angular and creating dynamic components, I now the only way is to use `ViewContainerRef` to create a new component in DOM; my important question is, does Angular itself create components the same way ?

If yes, can't we somehow access that container which holds the components ?

For those who've just started learning Angular and want to be helpful here ( thanks for that ) , I should say that I sincerely know how to use `ngIf` inside my template  :

I now what a `ngIf` is and what it does :

but :

```
 <div *ngIf="condition"></div>
```

is not what I mean, simply because this will potentially remove what is inside my template, and I have to wrap every thing inside that div to make it work , which is not what I want.

I want to clear the template all together with `ngIf`ing the inside.

---

**UPDATE**:

To give some clarification :

In other words , it's like having a `ngIf` on host :

```
@Component({

  host:{
    '*ngIf':'shouldBeRemoved'
  }
})
class MyComponent{
```

I know you can't put ngIf on host because its directive and host only compiles static values , that's why I'm asking if there is a way to handle it with `viewContainerRef` or something .

Please do know get confused by putting `ngIf` inside the template , that's not what I want.

Thanks for your patience again.

Comment: what is that you are trying to achieve? ChildComponent should remove DOM Elements based on ngIf am I correct?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Because it sounds that you want to add an ngIf to the top level of your component

Comment: @eddyP23 , I thought my question has enough clarity , but as you guys keep asking what am I going to achieve, I'll say again : "I want to remove the component template conditionally "

Comment: Then just use the following:
<template [ngIf]='yourCondition'> {Insert your component logic here} </template>

Comment: NgIf removes (and not hides) the template as you ask

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgIf-directive.html
See last example for Syntax, says the same thing

Comment: Dude , you should really read the question, I don't want to remove an element from DOM, I'm inside a component and I want to remove my own template, where would you put that ngIf , :(

Comment: Yes, you are inside your component and you want to remove your own template, then surround your template by the html tag <template> and use ngIf inside it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no official way of removing a template from inside a component and for me it makes sense.
If you remove your template, who is gonna take care of putting it back.
This works in `ngIf` because `ngIf` first creates a `template` behind the scene and then embeds the element inside it, so it has a reference to the embedded element, therefore it can delete it or put it back.

Answer (score 6):

Here is what you are looking for:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'your-selector',
    template: '<template [ngIf]="showView"> Here is my component template </template> ',
})
class MyComponent{

    showView: boolean = true;

   onSomeButtonClick(condition){
       if (condition) {
          this.showView = false;
       } else {
          this.showView = true;
        }
   }
}
```

Now, just add some button with an onClick callback to call `onSomeButtonClick` with some param and you are done

Comment: This is a great solution for what is required in the question. There is a small mistake with ngIf syntax, it should be *ngIf and not [ngIf].

Comment: @MohitMittal , when you specify the template , there is no need for * anymore, because behind the scene *ngIf does that

Answer (score 1):

I can only answer base on my limited understanding of how angular2 and typescript work.

#### Short Answer

No.

#### Long Answer

At typescript level, template and the class look like separate part. However the template is actually part of the class declaration.

Once a component class is initiated, all those template variable binding, directive, etc, become bits and pieces inside the component object.

Changing, including removing(what the question is asking for), the template basically means re-writing the class, will need re-transcripting, then recompile/reinit by the angular2 engine.

In a programing point of view this is possible, especially with javascript objects, which can have method deleting all siblings and reinitiate everything. However, I don't see an angular2 way for a component to *reboot* itself.

Currently the closest technique I know of is dynamic component, of which the parent component can create and destroy. And it is mentioned in the question.

(*rebooting* a component is almost the same as dynamic component, difference is initiated internally or externally.)

Comment: thanks.
By "removing", I didin't mean to remove my code from the typescript class, I mean to remove the created element from DOM , which ngIf is doing

Comment: @Milad So you want the same effect of `*ngIf`, but control that behavior using only programming code, without any directive in template. Is my understanding accurate?

Comment: Sort of , think about it as having the ngIf on host , see my update in the question

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that the component that you want to it to remove itself, will be unmounted by its host with a boolean that's binded to ngIf.
in order for the component, to practically remove itself, the boolean should have the value of a state in redux, and that state will be set only by the component that you want it to be removed by itself :)